# C++ Digital Calculator Simulator

Tags: c++

I'm currently stuck on having to write a simulator for a real, old calculator (like those one dollar calculators, the ones with the buttons, in which you must enter your numbers one push-of-a-button at a time, can't write the Whole number directly and for now it is only in integers). I know for sure that there has to be a switch case for the 0-9 and one for the operators (including '='). Should break the cycle and print the result of the calculation, but I can use as many operators as I want in the each "session" (ex: 123+7-89/6*8+3). I am finding trouble in connecting the two loops and in printing the result. Thank you so much in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int execute(int n1, int n2, char c);

int main()
{
int acc, num=0;
char c, op;
cin>>c;
while (1) {
    switch (c) {
        case '0': cout << "0";
        case '1': cout << "1";
        case '2': cout << "2";
        case '3': cout << "3";
        case '4': cout << "4";
        case '5': cout << "5";
        case '6': cout << "6";
        case '7': cout << "7";
        case '8': cout << "8";
        case '9': cout << "9";
        num=num*10+static_cast<int>(c-'0');
        acc=num;
        op=c;
        acc= execute(acc, num, op);
    }
}

return 0;
}

int execute(int n1, int n2, char c) {
do {
    switch (c) {
        case '+': return (n1+n2);
        case '-': return (n1-n2);
        case '*': return (n1*n2);
        case '/': return (n1/n2);
        case '=': return true;
    }
} while (!'=')
}
```

Comment: You don't need the switch for the digits. You can push a `char` to `std::cout`.

Comment: Your switch is broken because you don't use break; however as @FrançoisAndrieux mentioned you don't want a switch anyways.

Comment: I understand; would that work with the operators too? (Thank you so much for helping)

Comment: You only read input *once*. I suggest you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: in `int execute(int n1, int n2, char c)` remember that once code hits a return the function is done. With that said, I am not sure why you have a do {} while() at all since you execute a single operation.

Comment: Some `break` statements could be very useful as well.

Comment: not an issue here, but reconsider `while (!'=')`, which always exits immediately.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the tips (and sorry for the exareggation about calculators, unfortunately I'm still not that good in English and was trying to get the point across :') ). I will surely learn as fast as I can to debug! I have fixed the first part with the std::cout, and the code looks something like this:

Comment: I will absolutely see the breaks and the while (thank you all again for all the help)

Comment: while (1) {
            std::cout << c;
            num=num*10+static_cast<int>(c-'0');
            acc=num;
            op=c;
            acc= execute(acc, num, op);
            
        }

Comment: int execute(int n1, int n2, char c) {
    while(!'=')  {
        switch (c) {
            case '+': return (n1+n2);
            case '-': return (n1-n2);
            case '*': return (n1*n2);
            case '/': return (n1/n2);
            break;
        }
        
    }

Comment: You don't want any loop at all in `int execute(int n1, int n2, char c)`

Comment: `case '=': return true;` is not going to do what you want. You want to return the total. Is that in `n1` ??